# Estimating MAU from a sample

Tags: sampling, sql

I need to calculate MAU (or just the number of unique users) of a large service, with several conditions. I have a huge log (100B+ lines) of user actions, so I need to select some lines (satisfying the conditions) from this log and then just take count(distinct user_id) on the filtered set. But the filtering condition is complex and slow, so we cannot do it on the whole log. But we can work on a random sample from the full original log, say, 1B lines from it.
How can we correctly estimate the MAU from this sample, with no more than 1% relative error? Can we get a confidence interval for the true MAU?

I hear this is called "cardinality estimation", but I still have not found the definitive answer. Does it make sense to preprocess data in some way to make such estimates or use some special way of sampling for this purpose?